# Ignore SSL certificates error in axios/fetch call in react-native expo android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, ssl, expo

I just started using react-native and am trying to build an android app with it.. I used create-react-native-app and used the expo template. But I'm not able to fetch data from my server kepp getting "Network Error". My server doesn't have a valid certificate currently. Is there any way to ignore ssl certificate errors in my fetch calls?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, only use the **http** instead <strike>https</strike>, and set the following line in your manifest

```
<application
...
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
...>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way that I found to resolve is downgrade the version.

"axios": "0.24.0"