# How to ignore SSL cert issues in fetch() call when using Expo?

Tags: react-native, fetch, expo, rn-fetch-blob

seems there's no way in react-native to disable SSL verification during fetch() call. Someone mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51130878/how-to-disable-ssl-check-in-react-native-xmlhttprequest-api-or-in-fetch-api) that rn-fetch-blob can achieve this, but as one of the comments alludes to - Expo isn't compatible with rn-fetch-blob (and building an APK, then sending to device would make development painful). Any solutions folks have used here?

Note - similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59835051/ignore-ssl-certificates-error-in-axios-fetch-call-in-react-native-expo-android) but I'm querying a public domain (strengthlevel.com) so don't have control over certs or protocol.

Answer (score 0):

In recent Expo, you can use tunneling to achieve SSL traffic via an unsecured connection ([Expo Documentation on tuneling](https://docs.expo.dev/more/expo-cli/#tunneling)):

"To enable tunneling, first install @expo/ngrok:"

```
npm i -g @expo/ngrok
```

"Then run the following to start your dev server from a tunnel URL:"

```
npx expo start --tunnel
```